# Find elements in a document with a string/array using shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, shift

I have a document with some HTML:

```
<ul class="cl">
    <li> <span>span</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I also have a string representing a CSS path to certain elements:

```
var _string = 'div p ul.cl li span';
```

I would like to find the matching path based on document, so:

```
ul.cl li span
```

So I figured to use `shift()` to chop of the string one piece at a time and then try to find it in the document. If a match is found I will alert:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {

    if ($(_array.shift()).length) {
        alert(_array)
    }

}
```

This is alerting `li,span` but there is also `ul.cl` on the page Why doesn't it alert `ul.cl,li,span`? What am I doing wrong?

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67xs04f1/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use [.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). It changes the array which makes your for loop do unexpected things. Use array index to get elements like below.

```
var _string = 'div p ul.cl li span';

var _array = _string.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
    var el = _array[i]
    if ($(el).length) {
        alert(el)
    }

}
```

Updated [JS-Fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/67xs04f1/4/)

Answer (score 1):

edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/67xs04f1/6/

```
var _string = 'div p ul.cl li span';

var _array = _string.split(' ');

$.each(_array, function (i, item) {
    if ($(item).length) {
        alert(item);   
    }
});
```

try that

Comment: Thanks for the Jquery version

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not run on `_array.length` if you're modifying it inside the loop by `shift()`, or anything else for that matter.

Now, for why it alerts what it alerts after you do this change:

```
var arrLength = _array.length;   
for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

    if ($(_array.shift()).length) {
        alert(_array)
    }

}
```

The first match will be on `$(_array.shift()).length` when `_array.shift()` produces ul.cl, and after the shift the array content is `li,span`.

That's why the first alert is `li,span`.

Similarly, the next alert will be `span` since it will find an `li`.

Lastly, the alert is an empty one since after the last shift the array is empty.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67xs04f1/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
[0]:http://jsfiddle.net/67xs04f1/9/
```

there is two sample if want an element one by one and if u remove an element for and want perticular element